# How to manage CMD using python

Tags: python, com, msdn

I would like to run a cmd process from my python script and have the ability to manage it, like execute commands as python test.py input 1 input 2, make it visible or hide, insert input and read the output etc. The idea is like a com object of Excel or IE.

Does anybody know a way to do that?

Comment: Just set the environment variable for python.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].